# Iterative parameter updates on student-t distribution (and approach for other distributions)

Tags: distributions, bayesian, lognormal-distribution, t-distribution, parameterization

In a paper I found an iterative algorithm based on Bayes working with the following distribution and update criteria:

[image: Distribution parameter update]

In another source, I found the same update criteria in a whole different context.

**My Questions:**

- Is there any literature/paper/book where these parameter definitions and parameter update criteria can be found (because they seem generally valid for their respective distribution)?
- Is this a common update for this distribution and how could I approach finding the update criteria for other distributions? (e.g. lognormal, gamma, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that they're assuming Gaussian data with a conjugate prior on unknown mean and variance. When you marginalize out $\mu,\sigma$, the posterior predictive follows a Student's T. (See [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) starting on p. 9 and you'll recognize the update equations, noting that the $\beta$ update continues onto the following page.)

You could approach this for other distributions by considering their [conjugate priors and posterior hyperparameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions), then deriving update rules to suit.

Comment: Just one more question: The Student-T distribution is not listed in the Wikipedia "Conjugate priors" table. I know that it is not part of the exponential family but shouldn't it be listed anyway?

Comment: It's in there as a posterior predictive, are you asking if it should be listed as a likelihood?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I was searching for it as a likelihood under its particular name.

Comment: Sorry that I can't edit my comments, another question came to mind just now. Do you know how the parameters in the image above were computed? Especially sigma and nu, as I can't find where these definitions come from.

Comment: Sure, take a look at section 3.5 in my first link. (Short version: you can recognize the Student's T after some lengthy algebra.)

Comment: Mhh, in 3.5 I can just find the hint regarding the update rules but no reference to the parameters. \sigma = (\beta \kappa + 1)/(\alpha \kappa) for example. Taking literature into account, I rather thought that \sigma = \nu / (\nu - 2) for example. Where do \alpha , \beta and \kappa for the Student-T come from? Or maybe I am just blind.

Comment: Let's back up and remember how Student's T arises here: If you assume normally distributed data with unknown mean and precision (inverse variance), and would like to construct a conjugate prior, you'll wind up with a Normal-Gamma model. ($\alpha, \beta$ are parameters of the Gamma distribution.) If you integrate out the model parameters to get the posterior predictive, you'll get a form recognizable as a Student's T. Equation (110) relates that parameters of the component distributions to the Student T predictive posterior. That help?